# How does EIP 1337 guarantee full payments of subscriptions without holding all the funds in escrow?

Tags: eip

I'm struggling to find out how the EIP 1337 makes sure that the subscriber holds enough funds to pay for the (whole) subscription without holdings the whole amount of the funds in escrow?

Does someone has an answer (not the Github)?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It essentially relies on a Layer 2 server(s) which will pick up your pre-signed transactions. That is, for a full-year subscription with payments due every month, there will be 12 pre-approved transactions. There is no way to know beforehand if the user will have enough funds in the future, but this is resolved off-chain by disabling access to the said offered service.

Depending on the application incentives, you may need to pay extra gas, albeit in most cases the payee is a business and it will process the payments for you.

You could have a read on the [ERC-948](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/948) thread and, importantly, [meta transactions](https://medium.com/@austin_48503/ethereum-meta-transactions-90ccf0859e84).

So the answer is that EIP-1337 doesn’t make sure the user has enough funds.

Comment: I think this means the answer to the question is "It doesn't."